# Change object view but keep record type

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, page-layout, record-type, lightning-record-page

I have been requested to do two different page views for an object for the same user.

Both must be able to be configured using layouts.

I am not allowed to change the record type because it has business implications. I think since I need to keep the record id both must be a record page.

Using configuration you can change the record type and associate each to a view, but since I can't change the record id I am looking for a coding way.

I think the point is to redirect from the record page to a lightning app page.
The problem is that I don´t know how to use the standard layouts in code.

How can I get two different views and change between them without changing the record type?

Comment: I'd be curious _why_ you need the two views. Once you know that, it may be possible to come up with an easier, more elegant solution. Assumedly, the different views will be presented based on the state of the record and that is something you can always hook into in your lightning layouts to present the user with different options.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**: This is opinion based.

For me, as an ISV partner developer, this is not a sensible requirement and would mean a lot of unnecessary coding of your own to replicate large chunks of what Salesforce already does for you. Additionally, you would need to provide the means to somehow select layouts for the record in some way (since Salesforce only supports by object and record type).

You should push back and let them know that this goes against Salesforce best practice, will take a lot of effort and will create a legacy of code that must be maintained going forward. If you use standard Salesforce functionality almost all of this headache is removed from you/the client and taken on by Salesforce.

Use of layouts is no longer the primary approach, but rather you should be using [Dynamic Forms](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5) (for those objects it is available for). These allow adapting presentation based on field data, which is probably ideal for what you are discussing.

NB: Salesforce is on a journey to get rid of Profiles, and layouts are one of the few elements still only manageable by profile.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found out a solution.

[image]

The solution @Phil W. suggests would work for custom objects, I am working with Opportunity (Standard object) so it is not the case here.

I am going to use the filter property of each component element and filter the components depending on the state of a field in the opportunity record.
This way I am able to create multiple views based on a record field same as it would happen with a record type.